# How to crop file content string on string slices swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I'm trying to crop string on slices and send them to the server. Let’s take an example: I have file with such size of its string - 813753. I have to crop it on slices with max size 10000.All below code will be in file picker function:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        
        let file = urls[0]
        do{
            let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: file.absoluteURL)
            let encodedString = String.init(data: fileData, encoding: .isoLatin1)!
            let fileName = file.lastPathComponent
            let time = Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)


}
}
```

At the beginning after selection I figure out whether file has result of division >0:

```
let sliceCounts = encodedString.count%10000 > 0 ? encodedString.count/10000 + 1 :  encodedString.count/10000
```

then in loop I'm trying to get file content slices:

```
for slice in 0...sliceCounts{
    let partSize = slice*10000
                    
    let content = encodedString.count%10000 > 0 && partSize >= encodedString.count
                        ? substring(from: partSize - 10000, to: encodedString.count, s: 
       encodedString) : substring(from: partSize, to: partSize+10000, s: encodedString)



}
```

I use such method for getting file part:

```
func substring(from : Int, to : Int, s : String) -> String {
        let start = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: from)
        let end   = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: to)
        return String(s[start..<end])
    }
```

And the problem is that I receive such error:

```
Fatal error: String index is out of bounds: file Swift/StringCharacterView.swift, line 60
```

It happens when I'm trying to get the last slice. I think the problem is connected with this condition :

```
encodedString.count%10000 > 0 && partSize >= encodedString.count
```

and also I think that maybe I have some problems with sending indexes to my method, due to the error. Maybe someone will see where I make a mistake and will help :)

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues in your `for` loop, first you loop one iteration to much and secondly for the end of the string you need to consider that the last chunk might be smaller.

```
for slice in 0..<sliceCounts {
    let partSize = slice * maxSize

    let content: String
    if partSize + maxSize > encodedString.count {
        content = String(encodedString.suffix(encodedString.count - partSize))
    } else {
        content = encodedString.count%maxSize > 0 && partSize >= encodedString.count
            ? substring(from: partSize - maxSize, to: encodedString.count, s:
                            encodedString) : substring(from: partSize, to: partSize+maxSize, s: encodedString)
    }
}
```

Note that I used a constant `maxSize` instead of a hardcoded value in my code